# eclipse doesn't recognize @testVisible notation

Tags: apex, eclipse

I get an error saying unknown annotation when I use the `@testVisible` KW in my class, when using the force.com IDE, however it works fine in the developer console.

Is there a bug? do I need to update the version of my IDE? I know that this annotation came out last year...https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Force.com IDE

Version: Summer '13 (28.0.1)

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't keeping your IDE up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to updated the IDE and force.com plugin. Older version of IDE does not recognize the latest keywords and throws error